# How do I pass data from the controller to the template view in ZF2 using Twig?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, twig

I have a problem with passing data from the controller to the template view. No matter how I try to put the data in the view file, I cannot access the data I'm passing from the template.

I've uploaded a test module here https://github.com/svenanders/Twiglytest

Controller:

```
 <?php
   namespace Twigly\Controller;

   use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
   use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
   class TwiglyController extends AbstractActionController 
   {
     public function twiglyAction()
    {   
        echo "go...";
        // return array('version'=> \Zend\Version\Version::VERSION);

        return new ViewModel(array(
            'data' => array("test"=>"test2"),


       ));
     }
   }
```

view:

```
{% for a in data %}
  <h2>{{ a }}1</h2>
{% endfor %}
...done
```

result:

```
go...


...done
```

Whereas I expected to receive some data between go... and ...done

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a shot in the dark but, can you try one of the following in your view?

```
{% for key,a in data %}
<h2>{{ a }}1</h2>
{% endfor %}
...done
```

OR

```
{{ data['test'] }}.
```

Comment: Yeah, that was a good idea, but didn't actually do anything (though it should've) ;) IDK what was up with Twig at the time (or something else I wrote), but it got sorted with an update. Thanks for taking the time to chime in with an answer.